# Python OWASP ZAP API doesn't seem to successfully authenticate http basic

Tags: php, python, basic-authentication, owasp, zap

I have a problem with using the API to do an authenticated scan of a website that I made. This (test) website uses HTTP Basic authentication. When initiating the scan it can't seem to find the web pages behind the login.

Below you can find the Python class (probably not perfect) which I made for the use of the ZAP API.

```py
    from time import sleep
    from pprint import pprint
    import json
    from pathlib import Path
    from zapv2 import ZAPv2
    from loginauthmethod import loginauthmethod

    with open(Path('../Scripts/config.json'), 'r') as f:
            config = json.load(f)

    class owaspzap():
        key = config['ZAProxy']['key']
        zap = ZAPv2(apikey=key)
        contextname = None
        contextid = None
        userid = None
        authisset = False
        target = None
        loginurl = None
        username = None
        password = None
        authmethod = loginauthmethod.NONE
        authmethodname = None
        authmethodconfigparams = None
        contextregex = None
        loggedinindicator = None
        loggedoutindicator = None
        credentials = None
        scanid = None
        realm = None

        def initialize(self, contextname, target, contextregex):
            self.contextname = contextname
            self.zap = ZAPv2(apikey=self.key)
            self.zap.core.new_session(apikey=self.key)
            self.contextid = self.zap.context.new_context(contextname=self.contextname, apikey=self.key)

            self.target = target
            self.contextregex = contextregex

            if(self.zap.core.alerts()):
                self.zap.core.delete_all_alerts(apikey=self.key)    

            self.zap.context.include_in_context(self.contextname, self.contextregex, apikey=self.key)

            self.zap.urlopen(self.target)

        def authenticateFORM(self, loginurl, username, password, loggedinindicator, loggedoutindicator, authmethod):
            if(authmethod != loginauthmethod.NONE):
                self.loginurl = loginurl
                self.username = username
                self.password = password
                self.authmethod = authmethod
                self.loggedinindicator = loggedinindicator
                self.loggedoutindicator = loggedoutindicator

                self.authmethodconfigparams = "loginUrl={0}&loginRequestData=username%3D%7B%25{1}%25%7D%26password%3D%7B%25{2}%25%7D".format(loginurl, username, password)

                self.authmethodname = self.authmethod.value
                self.zap.authentication.set_authentication_method(self.contextid, self.authmethodname, authmethodconfigparams=self.authmethodconfigparams, apikey=self.key)
                self.zap.authentication.set_logged_in_indicator(self.contextid, self.loggedinindicator, apikey=self.key)
                self.zap.authentication.set_logged_out_indicator(self.contextid, self.loggedoutindicator, apikey=self.key)
                self.userid = self.zap.users.new_user(self.contextid, self.username, apikey=self.key)
                self.credentials = "username={0}&password={1}".format(self.username, self.password)
                self.zap.users.set_authentication_credentials(self.contextid, self.userid, self.credentials, apikey=self.key)
                self.zap.users.set_user_enabled(self.contextid, self.userid, "true", apikey=self.key)
                self.zap.forcedUser.set_forced_user_mode_enabled(True, apikey=self.key)

                self.authisset = True

            else:
                print("Please specify authmethod.")

        def authenticateBASIC(self, loginurl, username, password, loggedinindicator, loggedoutindicator, authmethod, realm):
            if(authmethod != loginauthmethod.NONE):
                self.loginurl = loginurl
                self.username = username
                self.password = password
                self.authmethod = authmethod
                self.loggedinindicator = loggedinindicator
                self.loggedoutindicator = loggedoutindicator
                self.realm = realm

                self.authmethodconfigparams = "hostname={0}&realm={1}&port=80".format(self.loginurl, self.realm)

                self.authmethodname = self.authmethod.value
                self.zap.authentication.set_authentication_method(self.contextid, self.authmethodname, authmethodconfigparams=self.authmethodconfigparams, apikey=self.key)
                self.zap.authentication.set_authentication_method
                self.zap.authentication.set_logged_in_indicator(self.contextid, self.loggedinindicator, apikey=self.key)
                self.zap.authentication.set_logged_out_indicator(self.contextid, self.loggedoutindicator, apikey=self.key)
                self.userid = self.zap.users.new_user(self.contextid, self.username, apikey=self.key)
                self.credentials = "username={0}&password={1}".format(self.username, self.password)
                self.zap.users.set_authentication_credentials(self.contextid, self.userid, self.credentials, apikey=self.key)
                self.zap.users.set_user_enabled(self.contextid, self.userid, "true", apikey=self.key)
                self.zap.forcedUser.set_forced_user_mode_enabled(True, apikey=self.key)

                self.authisset = True

            else:
                print("Please specify authmethod.")

        def spider(self, target):
            if(self.authisset):
                self.scanid = self.zap.spider.scan_as_user(self.contextid, self.userid, url=target)
            else:
                self.scanid = self.zap.spider.scan(url=target, contextname=self.contextname)

            sleep(2)

            while (int(self.zap.spider.status(self.scanid)) < 100):
                sleep(2)

        def passive_scan(self):
            while (int(self.zap.pscan.records_to_scan) > 0):
                sleep(2)

        def active_scan(self, target):
            self.scanid = self.zap.ascan.scan(target)
            sleep(2)
            while (int(self.zap.ascan.status(self.scanid)) < 100):
                sleep(5)

        def get_alerts(self):
            return self.zap.core.alerts()

        def get_spider(self):
            return self.zap.spider.full_results(self.scanid)

        def context_remove(self):
            self.zap.context.remove_context(self.contextname, apikey=self.key)

        def __str__(self):
            return ("ContextName: " + str(self.contextname) + 
                ", ContextId: " + str(self.contextid) + 
                ", UserId: " + str(self.userid) + 
                ", AuthIsSet: " + str(self.authisset) + 
                ", Key: " + str(self.key) + 
                ", Zap: " + str(self.zap) +
                ", Target: " + str(self.target) +
                ", LoginUrl: " + str(self.loginurl) + 
                ", Username: " + str(self.username) + 
                ", Password: " + str(self.password) + 
                ", AuthMethod: " + str(self.authmethod.value) +
                ", AuthMethodConfigParams: " + str(self.authmethodconfigparams) +
                ", ContextRegex: " + str(self.contextregex) + 
                ", LoggedInIndicator: " + str(self.loggedinindicator) + 
                ", LoggedOutIndicator: " + str(self.loggedoutindicator) + 
                ", Credentials: " + str(self.credentials) + 
                ", ScanId: " + str(self.scanid)
            )
```

Below is the file that calls the OWASP ZAP class.

```py
def webapp(target, loginurl, username, password, contextregex, authmethod, loggedinindicator, loggedoutindicator, realm):
    retdata = {}
    if not 'http' in target:
        sys.exit()
    whatweb.initiate(target)
    links = dirb.initialize(target)

    zap = owaspzap()

    zap.initialize(str(datetime.now()), target, contextregex)

    if(authmethod == loginauthmethod.FORM_BASED_AUTHENTICATION):
        zap.authenticateFORM(loginurl, username, password, loggedinindicator, loggedoutindicator, authmethod)
    elif(authmethod == loginauthmethod.HTTP_AUTHENTICATION):
        zap.authenticateBASIC(loginurl, username, password, loggedinindicator, loggedoutindicator, authmethod, realm)

    zap.spider(target)
    zap.passive_scan()
    zap.active_scan(target)
    retdata["spider"] = zap.get_spider()
    retdata["alerts"] = zap.get_alerts()

    zap.context_remove()
    return retdata
```

The parameters used to call webapp are:

```
target = http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
loginurl = http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/login.php
username = 1234
password = qwer
contextregex = \Qhttp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/\E.*
authmethod = loginauthmethod.HTTP_AUTHENTICATION
loggedinindicator = .*This page is hidden.*
loggedoutindicator = .*Login failed.*
realm = test
```

Also I have the PHP files from the test website.

login.php

```php
<?php
    $LoginSuccessful = false;
    session_unset();

    if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){

        $Username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
        $Password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

        if ($Username == '1234' && $Password == 'qwer'){
            $LoginSuccessful = true;
        }
    }

    if (!$LoginSuccessful){
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="test"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

        print "Login failed!\n username=1234 and password=qwer";
        die;
    }
    else {
        print 'you reached the secret page!';
    }


?>

<form action="hiddenpage.php" method="post">
    <input type = "password" class = "form-control"
               name = "password" placeholder = "password = hiddenpage" >
    <button class = "btn" type = "submit" name = "login">submit</button>
</form>
```

logout.php

```php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl" dir="ltr" class="watermark">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="back.css" />
  </head>
  <body >
    asrgsregtsergsergserg
  </body>
</html>
```

index.php

```php
<form action="login.php">
    <button class = "btn" type = "submit" name = "login">Login</button>
</form>
```

hiddenpage.php

```php
<?php
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('Location: http://192.168.2.131/login.php');
        echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
        echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
    }
    echo shell_exec($_POST["mesje"]);
?>
This page is hidden!!!
<form action="hiddenpage.php" method="post">
    <input type = "text" class = "form-control"
               name = "mesje" placeholder = "password = hiddenpage" >
    <button class = "btn" type = "submit" name = "login">submit</button>
</form>
```

Also here is the output from ZAP.

```
67588 [ZAP-ProxyThread-1] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.control.Control  - Discard Session
67617 [ZAP-ProxyThread-1] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.control.Control  - New Session
67617 [ZAP-ProxyThread-1] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.control.Control  - New Session
67617 [ZAP-ProxyThread-1] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.control.Control  - Create and Open Untitled Db
67677 [ZAP-ProxyThread-1] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - dataFileCache commit start
67695 [ZAP-ProxyThread-1] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - dataFileCache commit end
67752 [ZAP-ProxyThread-1] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - Database closed
67899 [ZAP-ProxyThread-1] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - open start - state not modified
68116 [ZAP-ProxyThread-1] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - dataFileCache open start
68140 [ZAP-ProxyThread-1] INFO hsqldb.db..ENGINE  - dataFileCache open end
68936 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spider.SpiderThread  - Starting spidering scan on Context: 2019-06-12 12:06:50.023958 at Wed Jun 12 12:06:51 CEST 2019
68944 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spider initializing...
68981 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Starting spider...
68982 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Scan will be performed from the point of view of User: 1234
68994 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-1] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.users.User  - Authenticating user: 1234
69085 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-2] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.users.User  - Authenticating user: 1234
69122 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-2] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spidering process is complete. Shutting down...
69123 [ZAP-SpiderShutdownThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spider.SpiderThread  - Spider scanning complete: true
75090 [ZAP-ProxyThread-18] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.Scanner  - scanner started
75110 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - Scanning 2 node(s) from http://192.168.2.131
75111 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestPathTraversal strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
75406 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestPathTraversal in 0.296s with 33 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
75407 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestRemoteFileInclude strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
75529 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestRemoteFileInclude in 0.122s with 20 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
75530 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestServerSideInclude strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
75578 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestServerSideInclude in 0.048s with 8 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
75578 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestCrossSiteScriptV2 strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
75626 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestCrossSiteScriptV2 in 0.048s with 6 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
75626 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestPersistentXSSPrime strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
75656 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestPersistentXSSPrime in 0.03s with 2 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
75656 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestPersistentXSSSpider strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
75666 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestPersistentXSSSpider in 0.01s with 2 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
75667 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestPersistentXSSAttack strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
75672 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestPersistentXSSAttack in 0.005s with 0 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
75672 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestSQLInjection strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
76043 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestSQLInjection in 0.371s with 52 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
76043 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | CodeInjectionPlugin strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
76182 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | CodeInjectionPlugin in 0.139s with 16 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
76182 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | CommandInjectionPlugin strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
76499 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | CommandInjectionPlugin in 0.317s with 64 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
76499 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestDirectoryBrowsing strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
76513 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestDirectoryBrowsing in 0.014s with 2 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
76514 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestExternalRedirect strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
76618 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestExternalRedirect in 0.104s with 18 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
76618 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | BufferOverflow strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
76643 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | BufferOverflow in 0.024s with 2 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
76643 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | FormatString strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
76681 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | FormatString in 0.037s with 6 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
76681 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestInjectionCRLF strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
76761 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestInjectionCRLF in 0.08s with 14 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
76762 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | TestParameterTamper strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
76826 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host/plugin http://192.168.2.131 | TestParameterTamper in 0.065s with 8 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
76827 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - start host http://192.168.2.131 | ScriptsActiveScanner strength MEDIUM threshold MEDIUM
76828 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - skipped plugin [no scripts enabled] http://192.168.2.131 | ScriptsActiveScanner in 0.001s with 0 message(s) sent and 0 alert(s) raised.
76829 [Thread-10] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.HostProcess  - completed host http://192.168.2.131 in 1.724s
76829 [Thread-9] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.Scanner  - scanner completed in 1.739s
```

And the output from my program

```
{
    "spider": [{
        "urlsInScope": [{
            "processed": "true",
             "statusReason": "OK",
             "method": "GET",
             "reasonNotProcessed": "",
             "messageId": "4",
             "url": "http://192.168.2.131/",
             "statusCode": "200"
        },
         {
            "processed": "true",
             "statusReason": "Unauthorized",
             "method": "GET",
             "reasonNotProcessed": "",
             "messageId": "6",
             "url": "http://192.168.2.131/login.php",
             "statusCode": "401"
        }]
    },
     {
        "urlsOutOfScope": []
    },
     {
        "urlsIoError": []
    }],
     "alerts": [{
        "sourceid": "3",
         "other": "The X-XSS-Protection HTTP response header allows the web server to enable or disable the web browser's XSS protection mechanism. The following values would attempt to enable it: \nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; report=http://www.example.com/xss\nThe following values would disable it:\nX-XSS-Protection: 0\nThe X-XSS-Protection HTTP response header is currently supported on Internet Explorer,
         Chrome and Safari (WebKit).\nNote that this alert is only raised if the response body could potentially contain an XSS payload (with a text-based content type,
         with a non-zero length).",
         "method": "GET",
         "evidence": "",
         "pluginId": "10016",
         "cweid": "933",
         "confidence": "Medium",
         "wascid": "14",
         "description": "Web Browser XSS Protection is not enabled,
         or is disabled by the configuration of the 'X-XSS-Protection' HTTP response header on the web server",
         "messageId": "1",
         "url": "http://192.168.2.131/",
         "reference": "https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet\nhttps://blog.veracode.com/2014/03/guidelines-for-setting-security-headers/",
         "solution": "Ensure that the web browser's XSS filter is enabled,
         by setting the X-XSS-Protection HTTP response header to '1'.",
         "alert": "Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled",
         "param": "X-XSS-Protection",
         "attack": "",
         "name": "Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled",
         "risk": "Low",
         "id": "0"
    },
     {
        "sourceid": "3",
         "other": "This issue still applies to error type pages (401,
         403,
         500,
         etc) as those pages are often still affected by injection issues,
         in which case there is still concern for browsers sniffing pages away from their actual content type.\nAt \"High\" threshold this scanner will not alert on client or server error responses.",
         "method": "GET",
         "evidence": "",
         "pluginId": "10021",
         "cweid": "16",
         "confidence": "Medium",
         "wascid": "15",
         "description": "The Anti-MIME-Sniffing header X-Content-Type-Options was not set to 'nosniff'. This allows older versions of Internet Explorer and Chrome to perform MIME-sniffing on the response body,
         potentially causing the response body to be interpreted and displayed as a content type other than the declared content type. Current (early 2014) and legacy versions of Firefox will use the declared content type (if one is set),
         rather than performing MIME-sniffing.",
         "messageId": "1",
         "url": "http://192.168.2.131/",
         "reference": "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx\nhttps://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers",
         "solution": "Ensure that the application/web server sets the Content-Type header appropriately,
         and that it sets the X-Content-Type-Options header to 'nosniff' for all web pages.\nIf possible,
         ensure that the end user uses a standards-compliant and modern web browser that does not perform MIME-sniffing at all,
         or that can be directed by the web application/web server to not perform MIME-sniffing.",
         "alert": "X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing",
         "param": "X-Content-Type-Options",
         "attack": "",
         "name": "X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing",
         "risk": "Low",
         "id": "1"
    },
     {
        "sourceid": "3",
         "other": "",
         "method": "GET",
         "evidence": "",
         "pluginId": "10020",
         "cweid": "16",
         "confidence": "Medium",
         "wascid": "15",
         "description": "X-Frame-Options header is not included in the HTTP response to protect against 'ClickJacking' attacks.",
         "messageId": "1",
         "url": "http://192.168.2.131/",
         "reference": "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx",
         "solution": "Most modern Web browsers support the X-Frame-Options HTTP header. Ensure it's set on all web pages returned by your site (if you expect the page to be framed only by pages on your server (e.g. it's part of a FRAMESET) then you'll want to use SAMEORIGIN,
         otherwise if you never expect the page to be framed,
         you should use DENY. ALLOW-FROM allows specific websites to frame the web page in supported web browsers).",
         "alert": "X-Frame-Options Header Not Set",
         "param": "X-Frame-Options",
         "attack": "",
         "name": "X-Frame-Options Header Not Set",
         "risk": "Medium",
         "id": "2"
    },
     {
        "sourceid": "3",
         "other": "The X-XSS-Protection HTTP response header allows the web server to enable or disable the web browser's XSS protection mechanism. The following values would attempt to enable it: \nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; report=http://www.example.com/xss\nThe following values would disable it:\nX-XSS-Protection: 0\nThe X-XSS-Protection HTTP response header is currently supported on Internet Explorer,
         Chrome and Safari (WebKit).\nNote that this alert is only raised if the response body could potentially contain an XSS payload (with a text-based content type,
         with a non-zero length).",
         "method": "GET",
         "evidence": "",
         "pluginId": "10016",
         "cweid": "933",
         "confidence": "Medium",
         "wascid": "14",
         "description": "Web Browser XSS Protection is not enabled,
         or is disabled by the configuration of the 'X-XSS-Protection' HTTP response header on the web server",
         "messageId": "6",
         "url": "http://192.168.2.131/login.php",
         "reference": "https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet\nhttps://blog.veracode.com/2014/03/guidelines-for-setting-security-headers/",
         "solution": "Ensure that the web browser's XSS filter is enabled,
         by setting the X-XSS-Protection HTTP response header to '1'.",
         "alert": "Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled",
         "param": "X-XSS-Protection",
         "attack": "",
         "name": "Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled",
         "risk": "Low",
         "id": "6"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at the `API` tag's description you have used?

Comment: Use official docker images. Those things still contains bunch relatively ugly python code inside but you can run baseline scans with one command (change example.com to your website): `docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-baseline.py -t https://www.example.com` documentation is here https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Docker#zap-baseline-scan . If you want some additional functionality you can try to use gitlabs image instead gitlab https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/dast/ . Writing those test scripts by yourself is too complicated IMHO if you are not a OWASP ZAP dev

Answer (score 3):

I always recommend trying to get authentication working with the ZAP Desktop UI first - its much easier to see whats going on. Once you've got that working you can use the same scripts with the ZAP API. If you cant get it working with the ZAP desktop then you have no hope with the API I'm afraid.

See this FAQ for help with form based authentication, especially the diagnosing problems part: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQformauth

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. Do you happen to have a guide to http basic login? And is there a way to start the zap server in debug mode or something so it shows the contexts made and such

Comment: Get it working in GUI mode first (as suggested), then you can look around and see what's happening.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying it in the GUI right now. But I seem to do something wrong, I use the same variables as used above. Does anyone know( based on the web pages) what I should use for login and logout indicator. Also, is the regex for the scope correct?

Comment: You should refer to this FAQ https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQvulnappdvwa

Comment: @kingthorin I'm actually not using the DVWA and not using script authentication. I need to get the HTTP/NTLM Basic authentication working on the above PHP files

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question then. Ntlm != basic. Neither of which == form (Which the examples seem to include). If it isn't DVWA, you shouldn't reference it.

Comment: I have removed the reference to dvwa, and the basic method is located under the form method. And I said Ntlm because in the zap docs it is also mentioned together.